# how to compile ndk application in linux?

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk

I am using ndk r5. Please tell me how to compile application using this ndk in linux os?

Comment: Surely the nice ndk developers included a README with instructions along the lines of `./configure ; make ; make install` or whatever is appropriate for their tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an excellent explanation at http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Also, there are samples included with the ndk which should be of assistance.

Comment: its confused to me sorry i am Beginner...give me your simple explanation how to compile step by step please....if you give its very very useful to me....